# Topic of questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have recently asked on both Physics and Math StackExchange education-related questions (such as prerequisites for a textbook or features of online courses) and they have been reported. I would like to know why I can't ask this kind of questions here, and, if there is, in which community I can ask these.

Comment: Which questions are you referring to? I don't see any of your questions being on hold.

Comment: On the one hand, questions about prerequisites or curriculum are often closed on the grounds that they appear to be seeking personal advice.  On the other hand, such questions may also be more on-topic at [matheducators.se].

Comment: We are not responsible for what happens in Physics. I don't know what you mean by *reported*. And, echoing @Jack, it would be good to let us have a look at your "reported" questions, maybe we could tell you something about them.

Comment: First, I just ended up deleting the questions, so sorry about that. I mentioned the physics part here to avoid writing two different posts. And by "reported", I meant they were on hold. Also thanks to @XanderHenderson for the web recommendation, and thank you all for the support!

Comment: It's possible that closely related Questions to what you were asking have already been asked and answered on Math.SE or at Math Educators.  So searching for those related previous posts can help, both to formulate a better Question and avoid duplication of effort.